# issue building nestjs on remote docker with @nestjs/common

Tags: docker, nestjs

I have a NestJs project that is build on docker during gitlab CI.

In local, the dockerfile is building great with :

```
docker build -t server .
```

But during gitbal CI, with the same docker and same command, it crashes.  Especially with @nestjs/common. ( I learned that docker is made to works the same way on every environment. )

Here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:17-stretch-slim As builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY *.json *.ts ./
RUN npm install npm@8.5.0 --location=global
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENV NODE_ENV=production
# Some custom processes
RUN npm run build:prod


FROM node:17-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN npm install npm@8.5.0 --location=global
RUN npm install <-------------------------------------------- THE FAIL IS HERE
COPY --from=builder /app/dist  ./
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run launch:production
```

And here is the error :

```
Step 19/22 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in b009e097d4ae
npm WARN deprecated crypto@1.0.1: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
> server@0.0.1 postinstall
> rimraf dist && npm run build
> server@0.0.1 prebuild
> rimraf dist
> server@0.0.1 build
> nest build
node_modules/@nestjs/common/index.d.ts:10:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './serializer' or its corresponding type declarations.
10 export * from './serializer';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@nestjs/common/index.d.ts:11:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './services' or its corresponding type declarations.
11 export * from './services';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@nestjs/common/index.d.ts:12:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './utils' or its corresponding type declarations.
12 export * from './utils';
                 ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@nestjs/common/interfaces/nest-application-context-options.interface.d.ts:1:41 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../services/logger.service' or its corresponding type declarations.
1 import { LoggerService, LogLevel } from '../services/logger.service';
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@nestjs/common/interfaces/nest-application-context.interface.d.ts:2:41 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../services/logger.service' or its corresponding type declarations.
2 import { LoggerService, LogLevel } from '../services/logger.service';
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/index.d.ts:3:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './parse-bool.pipe' or its corresponding type declarations.
3 export * from './parse-bool.pipe';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/index.d.ts:4:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './parse-int.pipe' or its corresponding type declarations.
4 export * from './parse-int.pipe';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/index.d.ts:5:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './parse-float.pipe' or its corresponding type declarations.
5 export * from './parse-float.pipe';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/index.d.ts:6:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './parse-enum.pipe' or its corresponding type declarations.
6 export * from './parse-enum.pipe';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/index.d.ts:7:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './parse-uuid.pipe' or its corresponding type declarations.
7 export * from './parse-uuid.pipe';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/index.d.ts:8:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './validation.pipe' or its corresponding type declarations.
8 export * from './validation.pipe';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/parse-array.pipe.d.ts:3:55 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './validation.pipe' or its corresponding type declarations.
3 import { ValidationPipe, ValidationPipeOptions } from './validation.pipe';
                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.d.ts:1:10 - error TS2305: Module '"@nestjs/common"' has no exported member 'Logger'.
1 import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
           ~~~~~~
node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application-context.d.ts:1:35 - error TS2305: Module '"@nestjs/common"' has no exported member 'LoggerService'.
1 import { INestApplicationContext, LoggerService, LogLevel, ShutdownSignal } from '@nestjs/common';
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application-context.d.ts:1:50 - error TS2305: Module '"@nestjs/common"' has no exported member 'LogLevel'.
1 import { INestApplicationContext, LoggerService, LogLevel, ShutdownSignal } from '@nestjs/common';
```

I tried to force RUN npm unsinstall @nestjs/common && npm install @nestjs/common without any changes. I have redone all the step with cache cleared on gitlab etc.

Comment: Why are you using node 17 instead of node 16 or node 18? Odd versioned node builds are considered dev and unstable most of the time

Answer (score 0):

its hard to do without linking your libs setup..

just so you can be sure you have it correctly...

nest g library...

inside your libs / common is a directory filled with your common libraries...

```
+libs
 -common
   --src
     ---package1
     ---package2
     ---index.ts
```

inside index ts you are exporting the various modules members of the same directory... it looks like this.

```
export * from './database/database.module';
export * from './database/abstract.repository';
export * from './database/abstract.schema';
export * from './rmq/rmq.service';
export * from './rmq/rmq.module';
export * from './auth/auth.module';
export * from './auth/jwt-auth.guard';
export * from './constants/ServicePorts';
```

now when you want to use the common libraries you are doing so as followed.

```
import { RmqModule } from '@app/common';
import { Logger } from '@app/common'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

RUN npm run build

FROM node:alpine as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=prod

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

After in your compose try this

```
version: '3.8'
services:
   dev:
        container_name: service-dev
        image: myimage:1.0.0
        build:
            context: .
            target: development
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        command: npm run start:dev
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        networks:
            - nesjs-network
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
            - /usr/src/app/dist
        restart: unless-stopped

networks:
    nesjs-network:
```

I hope I have been helpful

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).